# Objective-C: Pass Variable to block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am very inexperienced with blocks. I have not mastered the syntax.

What I would like to do is to pass a date obtained in the first part of a method into a completion block so that the date is not set until the completion block runs (ie everything else is done).   Can anyone suggest how to do this?  Following gives error use of undeclared Identifier secondItem.

Edited:

```
- (void)myMethod: (NSInteger *) state {
    switch (state) {
        case 1: {
//do some stuff
} completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
                   //finish up
                }];
            }
            break;
        }
 default: {
Items* firstItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
           __ block NSDate* myDate = firstitem.date;   
Items* secondItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];


            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                secondItem.date = __block myDate;//ERROR THROWN HERE
            }];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post real code. The code you posted is a mess of bad indenting and syntax errors.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create completion block method right? If so have a look at this: https://xcodenoobies.blogspot.my/2017/07/how-to-basic-of-xcode-methods-functions.html

Answer (score -1):

Try using the __block keyword. The docs can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6)

Comment: I have been trying that...just edited the question.  adding __block before the myDate does get rid of the error there.  But I am still getting error for secondItem what would be the syntax for that?